# Is there any way to lookup twitter statuses more than 100 at once or to lookup statuses for a very large dataset?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, twitter, tweepy

As of now, I am having **150** *.CSV* containing a total of approx. **437,991,486** tweets ids.
It takes approx. 20+ hours even to get the desired output for just a single file. Can someone suggest the best method/approach to process the whole of my dataset?

```
def get_all_id_list():
    id_list =[]
    for file_name in glob.glob("*.csv"):
        file = open(file_name, 'r')
        for id in file:
            id_list.append(file.readline()[:-1])
    return id_list

def get_IN_AU_tweet_ids(api, id_list):
    i = 1
    id_list_in = []
    id_list_au = []
    id_list_length = len(id_list)
    try:
        for i in range((id_list_length // 100) + 1):
            ids = id_list[i * 100 : min((i + 1) * 100, id_list_length)]
            for tweet in api.statuses_lookup(ids):
                if hasattr(tweet.place, 'country_code'):
                    country_code = tweet.place.country_code
                    if country_code == 'IN':
                        id_list_in.append(tweet.id_str)
                    elif country_code == 'AU':
                        id_list_au.append(tweet.id_str)
    except tweepy.TweepError:
        print ('Something went wrong, quitting...')
    return id_list_in, id_list_au

def create_new_dataset(id_list_in, id_list_au):
    
    IN_DATASET_FILENAME = 'IN-Dataset.csv'
    AU_DATASET_FILENAME = 'AU-Dataset.csv'

    if(os.path.exists(IN_DATASET_FILENAME)):
        os.remove(IN_DATASET_FILENAME)

    if(os.path.exists(AU_DATASET_FILENAME)):
        os.remove(AU_DATASET_FILENAME)

    with open(IN_DATASET_FILENAME, 'w') as file:
        for id in id_list_in:
             file.write(id + '\n')

    with open(AU_DATASET_FILENAME, 'w') as file:
        for id in id_list_au:
            file.write(id + '\n')
    
if __name__ == "__main__":

    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit = True, wait_on_rate_limit_notify = True)

    if not api.verify_credentials():
        print("API Not Verified...!")
        exit(0)

    id_list =  get_all_id_list()
    id_list_in, id_list_au = get_IN_AU_tweet_ids(api, id_list)
    create_new_dataset(id_list_in, id_list_au)
```

Comment: Just curious: Why have you collected status id only instead of complete status records from the beginning ?

Comment: @javadude Actually, I have not collected Status ID's, it available here [IEEE-DataPort](https://ieee-dataport.org)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using free dev account.
Only up to 100 can be requested in one go. You are limited to 900 calls in 15min, that results in 90.000 x 4 per hour = 360.000 per hour. In 20 hours roughly 7,2 million records. I dont see a different way to retrieve the data.

Comment: Yup, Currently I'm Using free dev account.